# How to implement a "views" counter in a RESTful way?

Tags: http, rest, get

On most forum software there's a feature where every time someone reads a topic, the counter for that topic gets incremented. This allows users to see how many replies were made and also how many times the topic was read, e.g. for deciding if they want to participate in a topic.

Example:

```
                                           Replies    Views
hydro locked 3.2 M engine worth fixing?    81         2037
Japan Gets BMW M5 Limited Edition Model    760        16392
...
...
```

Surely enough if I click on, say, the first topic, a GET takes place and I can read that topic.

Now if someone else comes to the site right after me, he shall see:

```
                                           Replies    Views
hydro locked 3.2 M engine worth fixing?    81         2038
Japan Gets BMW M5 Limited Edition Model    760        16392
...
...
```

So the number of views for the first topic went, correctly, from 2037 to 2038. That counter is obviously stored on the server side.

So my question is simple: **How can GET be idempotent if a modification is happening on the server?**

Note that on all these forum software the number of views is an integral part of the site: a topic with very few replies but lots of views is typically one more interesting than a topic with very few replies *and* very few views, for example.

I understand that you can offload certain things (like analytics) to outside services (like Google Analytics) which can count for you things like pageviews, browser types, etc.
But what when the very act of a user GETting a resource is an integral part of your site?  It can be forum or auctions or whatever...

There are a great many sites where GET is modifying the state on the server. Does this mean these sites can never be RESTful?

Answer (score 3):

The reasoning behind `GET` being idempotent is that the client should not have to be concerned with the effects of getting a resource multiple times. You wouldn't want to perform a `GET` on a resource and having it create a topic in your forum, since the browser would not treat the request as having any side-effects and would merrily post a duplicate every time the URL was hit.

With a `POST` request, the behaviour for most browsers is different, where they will request you confirm that you *really* want to re-submit the request to the server, knowing it may have possible consequences that you care about.

I feel confident in saying that this is one of those cases where it's okay to have this side-effect, as the consequences are so small that the end-user will not care about accidentally requesting the resource a second time.

I would also advise that you want to be smart about what you consider a "view", such that it doesn't merely count the number of times a `GET` has been performed on the resource. That way duplicate requests are not considered views and the point around idempotency becomes even less relevant.